# Sortable and Filterable java script for visualforce table

Tags: visualforce, javascript, filters, sort

I have a visualforce page which displays the activities (events, tasks, notes, files) from a account in a table. Some accounts have a huge number of activities and it would be comfortable to sort or filter the table.
I found a good solution to sort from https://www.j-berkemeier.de/TableSort.html# but not filtering. Do you know a java script that can do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do sorting/filtering/pagination in VF pages, then [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) always proves to be useful.

One example can be found in [this](https://force201.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/client-side-sorting-and-pagination-of-an-apexpageblocktable/) blog.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ok noted, thanks @identigral